# Romanian IMO TST 1989

Tags: geometry

Let $A,B,C$ be variable points on edges $OX,OY,OZ$ of a trihedral angle $OXYZ$,
respectively. Let $OA = a$, $OB = b$, $OC = c$ and $R$ be the radius of the circumsphere $S$ of $OABC$. Prove that if points $A,B,C$ vary so that $a+b+c= R+1$, then the sphere $S$ remains tangent to a fixed sphere.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I don't really know how to approach it,this is why I posted it here.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a diagram? Usually when given lots if information about a complex geometry problem, Diagrams make your life easier

Comment: I have and it didn't help.